# Escape NSString for javascript input

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, escaping, ascii

I have a string of ASCII characters (created randomly by [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", someNumber]), and I want to use that string as input for a javascript method. Something like:

```
[webView_ stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my_javascript_method(\"%@\")", myASCIIString]];
```

How can I escape the NSString? I tried to look into encodeURI and decodeURI, but haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: For the record: `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is Unicode correct; you don't have to escape non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By ASCII, I presume you mean it's a byte in the range 0x00 to 0x7F.  In this range, according to http://www.json.org the only characters you need to escape are `\`, `"`, and the control characters: 0x00-0x1F and 0x7F.  The control characters get a bit tricky if you're doing simple substitutions, so I'd go through character by character to escape the string, maybe something like this (not tested at all):

```
const char *chars = [myASCIIString UTF8String];
NSMutableString *escapedString = [NSMutableString string];
while (*chars)
{
    if (*chars == '\\')
        [escapedString appendString:@"\\\\"];
    else if (*chars == '"')
        [escapedString appendString:@"\\\""];
    else if (*chars < 0x1F || *chars == 0x7F)
        [escapedString appendFormat:@"\\u%04X", (int)*chars];
    else
        [escapedString appendFormat:@"%c", *chars];
    ++chars;
}
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my_js_function(\"%@\")", escapedString];
```

Comment: This solution works, but it has two bugs.  First, this will not escape double quotes correctly.  It should read `"\\\""` instead of `"\""`.  Second, it will append the escaped string to the original string, instead of creating a new one.  The second line should read something like `NSMutableString *escapedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];`.

Comment: Escaping non-ASCII is not necessary. At least since iOS 5, UIWebView takes non-ASCII literals fine. And you're not doing it right anyway; it'll break with genuine upper-range Unicode characters.

Comment: The obvious audition in this day and age is to use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) but beware of [subtle differences](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) between JS and JSON. In any case, ASCII input is sufficient for this particular question.

Answer (score 15):

`NSJSONSerialization` is right there in the corner. To escape NSString to Javascript string literal is **hard** and could be done wrong easily. (`JSONKit` use lines of code to deal with it https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/blob/82157634ca0ca5b6a4a67a194dd11f15d9b72835/JSONKit.m#L1423)

Below is a little category method to escape the `NSString` object.

```
#import "NSString+JavascriptEscape.h"

@implementation NSString (JavascriptEscape)

- (NSString *)stringEscapedForJavasacript {
    // valid JSON object need to be an array or dictionary
    NSArray* arrayForEncoding = @[self];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayForEncoding options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString* escapedString = [jsonString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, jsonString.length - 4)];
    return escapedString;
}

@end
```

Also, one thing to notice, you've gotta use double quotes in the argument to the javascript function. E.g.,

```
NSString *javascriptCall = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyJavascriptFunction(\"%@\")", escapedString];

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCall];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! The only thing that could be mentioned is that this escapes double quotes, so you should use double quotes in your stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString call. I've put an example in an answer below.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisPrince, just append your suggestion to the answer!

Answer (score 10):

After countless hours of researching a solution here is what i came up with.  Its turns out i was running into an issue where i wasn't escaping the carriage return \r so this function solved my problems.

```
-(NSString *)addBackslashes:(NSString *)string {
    /*

     Escape characters so we can pass a string via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

     */

    // Escape the characters
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"\\\'"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"\\r"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\f" withString:@"\\f"];
    return string;
}
```

Here is a great website i found that lead me to this solution. http://www.wilsonmar.com/1eschars.htm

Comment: Fixed my problem !

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the relevant part of the ES5 specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.8.4):

> All characters may appear literally in a string literal except for the closing quote character, backslash, carriage return, line separator, paragraph separator, and line feed. Any character may appear in the form of an escape sequence.

There are backslash escapes for some characters (which you can find a couple of pages down), and any character can be represented in hex as `\uXXXX`. They're explained (with examples) a couple of pages down in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution which will work with extended ASCII symbols (eg Latin symbols) and/or unicode, you can use this:

```
- (NSString*) escapeStringForJavascript:(NSString*)input
{
    NSMutableString* ret = [NSMutableString string];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        unichar c = [input characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c == '\\')
        {
            // escape backslash
            [ret appendFormat:@"\\\\"];
        }
        else if (c == '"')
        {
            // escape double quotes
            [ret appendFormat:@"\\\""];
        }
        else if (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7E)
        {
            // if it is a printable ASCII character (other than \ and "), append directly
            [ret appendFormat:@"%c", c];
        }
        else
        {
            // if it is not printable standard ASCII, append as a unicode escape sequence
            [ret appendFormat:@"\\u%04X", c];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I don't know how this behaves with code points above that representable by a unichar. It seems like such characters cannot be represented in javascript either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything similar to:

```
[webView_ stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my_javascript_method(escape(\"%@\"))", myASCIIString]];
```

Just dropping the escape function into the string call may work for you. It really depends WHY you want this escaped

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work, the method wasn't called.
The reason I want it to escape is just because my ASCII string contains some unreadable characters (since it's created from ASCII of random numbers from 0-255), and it breaks the input.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow on to @zetachang's answer above. You've gotta use double quotes in the argument to the javascript function. E.g.,

```
NSString *javascriptCall = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyJavascriptFunction(\"%@\")", escapedString];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCall];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert the string into a JSON array and then paste the resulting JSON String into the JavaScript function parameter. This way I don't have to worry about whether the JSON string is contained within a single quote or double quote.

```
NSString* inputString = ... // your raw string to escape
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@[inputString] options:0 error:nil];
NSString* jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* jsScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourFunction(%@[0])",jsString];
// then pass jsScript to a JavaScript interpreter
```